# Existe alguma maneira alternativa de utilizar chaves estrangeiras em tabelas MyISAM?

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e preciso relacionar duas tabelas, logicamente, poderia utilizar chaves estrangeiras...O problema é que o banco de dados que estou utilizando só permite tabelas MyISAM que não tem suporte a chaves estrangeiras como o InnoDB. Sendo assim, como poderia contornar esse problema sem ter que utilizar tabelas InnoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chaves estrangeiras em MySQL são usadas para verificar e garantir a `referential integrity`, não para fazer `join` entre tabelas.

A única alternativa é ser você a [fazer o trabalho](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html) que é feito pela base de dados para garantir a `referential integrity`.

No entanto, você pode continuar a fazer `join` entre as tabelas relacionadas através dessas colunas, da mesma forma como faz no caso de chaves estrangeiras.

ou seja:

```
SELECT * FROM tabell1 INNER JOIN tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.id;
```

continua a ser válido

Comment: Ou seja: você precisa certificar-se de que em todos os pontos de sua aplicação que façam algum tipo de modificação nas tabelas envolvidas será garantida a manutenção da integridade referencial. Em termos práticos eu optaria por mudar o engine para InnoDB, é muito mais simples.

Comment: Não em todos os pontos, você pode utilizar `Triggers` de forma a centralizar essa verificação. Veja: [Enforcing Foreign Keys Programmatically in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html)